# JMeter: Groovy code for moving files from one directory to another stopped working. Any better approaches?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I had used the below mentioned Groovy code in the JSR223 Sampler to move my file from one directory to another. This was working until a few days back, now it no longer does. Any suggestions on how to get it working?
Also, I tried using a Beanshell sampler to perform the same task, but was not successful with that as well. Open to alternative approaches. Thanks in advance.

*Groovy Code in JSR223 Sampler:*

```
def sourceFile = new File('C:/Work/test.xml')
def destinationFile = new File('M:/temp/test.xml')
destinationFile << sourceFile.text
```

*Java code in Beanshell Sampler:*

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

File sourceFile = new File('C:/Work/test.xml');
File destinationFile = new File('M:/temp/test.xml');
FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **move** the file I would rather suggest using [File.renameTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) function like:

```
def sourceFile = new File('C:/Work/test.xml')
def destinationFile = new File('M:/temp/test.xml')

def success = sourceFile.renameTo(destinationFile)

if (success) {
    log.info('File has been successfully moved')
}
else {
    log.error('Failed to move the file')
}
```

If you're looking for an alternative approach it could be using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) and invoking [`move` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move) from there

Also check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, if Groovy script fails somewhere somehow most probably you will be able to find the reason or explanation there